# Spring OAuth oauth/token returns 404 war on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, http, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have followed the example here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnJsspvxE1c
to setup OAuth on my spring war application.
Since I am using spring 4.0.6.RELEASE and spring-security-oauth2 2.0.7.RELEASE I had to adapt it.

HTTP Get on /oauth/token returns 404
(Since my war name is kma.war then the request is to /kma/oauth/token)

Security filters seem to work fine according to the logs. 
But I dont see the call to the TokenEndpoint bean, I even remote debugged and put a breakpoint on it and nothing. Notice the last line in the log below.

```
.08:27:06.798 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token' 
.08:27:06.798 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token' 
.08:27:06.799 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client-id=kma-client&username=admin@kampyle.com&password=123; Attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] 
.08:27:06.799 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client-id=kma-client&username=admin@kampyle.com&password=123; Attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] 
.08:27:06.800 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90550640: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@7798: RemoteIpAddress: 10.0.2.2; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS 
.08:27:06.800 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90550640: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@7798: RemoteIpAddress: 10.0.2.2; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS 
.08:27:06.803 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@270d09d0, returned: 0 
.08:27:06.803 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@270d09d0, returned: 0 
.08:27:06.806 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@48ff4ab7, returned: 1 
.08:27:06.806 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@48ff4ab7, returned: 1 
.08:27:06.808 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful 
.08:27:06.808 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful 
.08:27:06.809 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object 
.08:27:06.809 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object 
.08:27:06.810 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client-id=kma-client&username=admin@kampyle.com&password=123 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain 
.08:27:06.810 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client-id=kma-client&username=admin@kampyle.com&password=123 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain 
.08:27:06.811 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally 
.08:27:06.811 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally 
.08:27:06.812 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed 
.08:27:06.812 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I do see the match of the url to the TokenEndpoint Bean at the beginning of the log.

```
.08:24:05.230 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/oauth/confirm_access],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.getAccessConfirmation(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception 
.08:24:05.230 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/oauth/confirm_access],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.getAccessConfirmation(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception 
.08:24:05.277 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal) 
.08:24:05.277 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal) 
.08:24:05.283 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[POST],params=[user_oauth_approval],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal) 
.08:24:05.283 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[POST],params=[user_oauth_approval],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal) 
.08:24:05.284 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException 
.08:24:05.284 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException 
.08:24:05.292 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException 
.08:24:05.292 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException****
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>KMA Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/spring/kmaAppContext.xml
            classpath:/spring/security/kmaSecurityContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/spring/kmaAppContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my kmaAppContext.xml

```
<beans
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kma" />
</beans>
```

And Last but not least, here is my security context

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.kma.security.UserDetailsService">
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <!--<security:user-service id="userService">-->
                <!--<security:user name="test" password="pass" authorities="customer" />-->
            <!--</security:user-service>-->
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />

    </security:http>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="kampyle/client"/>
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Authorization Server Configuration of the server is used to provide
    implementations of the client details service and token services and to enable
    or disable certain aspects of the mechanism globally. -->
    <oauth:authorization-server
            client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <!-- Client Definition -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

        <oauth:client client-id="kma-client"
                      authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect"
                      authorities="ROLE_USER"
                      redirect-uri="/web"
                      scope="read,write,trust"
                      access-token-validity="30"
                      refresh-token-validity="600"/>

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <!-- Token Store  -->
    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"/>
    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
        <!-- VIV -->
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
    </authentication-manager>
    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <!--<security:http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true">-->

        <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/admin/**"-->
                                <!--access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />-->
        <!--<security:http-basic />-->
        <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**"-->
                                <!--access="isAuthenticated()" />-->
        <!--<security:http-basic />-->
    <!--</security:http>-->

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have loaded the XML files twice and the security `Filter` that you hit has no `Servlet` in its context, so there is no way for it to handle the request. I recommend not using web.xml and switching to Spring Boot to get things working. If you prefer not to do that look at an old version of the sparklr2 sample (e.g. 1.0.5) and steal the [web.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/1.0.x/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) from there. Here it is:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        classpath:/spring/security/kmaSecurityContext.xml
        classpath:/spring/kmaAppContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Hi Dave. How did you figure that i loaded xml twice? which xml? I need to keep using web.xml for now. What is the main difference in the web.xml you pasted?

Comment: These two files: `classpath:/spring/kmaAppContext.xml,classpath:/spring/security/kmaSecurityContext.xml` are loaded twice (once in a servlet and once in a context loader listener).

Comment: I need to keep using web.xml for now. What is the main difference in the web.xml you pasted?

Comment: Should I keep the context xmls in the context loader and remove it from the servlet? If I do i get an error that it cant find appServletContext.xml, which is why i added it there.

Comment: I had a comment in my web.xml. I replaced it with explicit paths to you XML.

Comment: Update: I misread your config at first, so there are no duplicate files. The point about the servlet not being available in the filter context is still valid. I edited the web.xml to reflect this.

Comment: thanks, going to try that. Would it make sense to create two context xmls. One with all my beans, component scan of my services etc, and one with the mvc:annotaion-driven and component scan of my controllers? Also, a more importatn question what it the significance of org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring in the security filter?

Comment: I don't see the value in having 2 contexts (I know it's common for historical reasons). Why not get it working and then change it if you feel like you need to? The `FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring` tells the security filter to look for an application context in the `ServletContext` with that name ("spring" is the name of the servlet).

Comment: I must be going crazy: looked again and `classpath:/spring/kmaAppContext.xml` is definitely duplicated in your web.xml. I de-duped it in mine.

Comment: i think you accidently put kmaAppContext twice in the servlet contextConfiguration

Comment: OK, we are advancing now. Now I get a 405 Method Not Allowed for a GET request and a 401 Unauthorized for a POST request. I know that eventually i would need to use an authentication header, but for now i would like to keep it working with username password as query parameters. I understood from docs that including clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter would do that, but it doesnt work

Comment: This is the URL i am calling: http://localhost:8080/kma/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client-id=kma-client&username=admin&password=123

Comment: Probably not since you are sending "client-id" instead of "client_id".

Comment: hi Dave. first i want to thank you for your help so far. I've been banging my head on this for 2 days. I changed the URL to http://localhost:8080/kma/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin&password=123. It fails with "Bad client credentialsinvalid_client". I can see the log saying "DaoAuthenticationProvider - User 'kma-client' not found ".  looks like its trying to authenticate the client name as user. The edpoint is set

Comment: That's expected. You have to authenticate the client. Did you send the client credentials in a header?

Comment: The issue was that clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter authenticationManager pointed to authenticationManager instead of clientAuthenticationManager. I fixed that. and the client is authorized correctly, but the user authentication fails. Ill put in an answer with my new web.xml file and securityContext. I am advancing an inch a day.

Comment: You might make your life a lot easier if you used one of the integration test samples to get started instead of a blog based on an old version (e.g. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/vanilla)

Comment: hi Dave. First i really appreciate your help. I am tryng to find an example with xml configuration, not java configuration. The entire project is currently not using java configuration, and i would like to keep to the standard.

Comment: Another thing is this demo is spring boot, while we are using deployment to tomcat

Comment: Spring Boot actually doesn't have any OAuth features yet, so all the code in those samples is 100% portable  to a non-Boot application (apart from which Spring Boot supports deployment to Tomcat if you need to do that).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of help from Dave I have fixed my web.xml and my security context xml. I managed to get to a point where the oauth/token end point is available, and the client id is verified. User authentication still fails though.

Log shows client authentication success

```
.12:38:10.404 [http-nio-8080-exec-48] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.c.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d7afe829: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@93b2ea19: Username: kma-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
```

Log shows user verification fails:

```
.12:38:10.439 [http-nio-8080-exec-48] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.w.BasicAuthenticationFilter - Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'admin@kma.com' 
.12:38:10.459 [http-nio-8080-exec-48] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider 
.12:38:10.459 [http-nio-8080-exec-48] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider 
.12:38:10.460 [http-nio-8080-exec-48] DEBUG o.s.s.a.d.DaoAuthenticationProvider - User 'admin@kma.com' not found 
.12:38
```

Here is my updated web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>KMA Web Application</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.kmaApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>kmaApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:/spring/servlet-context.xml
                classpath:/spring/kmaAppContext.xml
                classpath:/spring/security/kmaSecurityContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>kmaApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my updated kmaSecurityContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.kma.security.UserDetailsService">
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <!--<security:user-service id="userService">-->
                <!--<security:user name="test" password="pass" authorities="customer" />-->
            <!--</security:user-service>-->
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />

    </security:http>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value=“kma/client"/>
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Authorization Server Configuration of the server is used to provide
    implementations of the client details service and token services and to enable
    or disable certain aspects of the mechanism globally. -->
    <oauth:authorization-server
            client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <!-- Client Definition -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

        <oauth:client client-id="kma-client"
                      authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect"
                      authorities="ROLE_USER"
                      redirect-uri="/web"
                      scope="read,write,trust"
                      access-token-validity="30"
                      refresh-token-validity="600"/>

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <!-- Token Store  -->
    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"/>
    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
        <!-- VIV -->
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <!--<security:http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true">-->

        <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/admin/**"-->
                                <!--access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />-->
        <!--<security:http-basic />-->
        <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**"-->
                                <!--access="isAuthenticated()" />-->
        <!--<security:http-basic />-->
    <!--</security:http>-->

</beans>
```

Comment: I tried changing <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager"> to use alias instead of id. <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">. This seems to work for authentication of the user. But I am back to square one. 404.

Comment: This is what i see in the log now: FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d7afe829: Principal: User@93b2ea19: Username: kma-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER 
AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@10e504fc, returned: 0 
FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful

Comment: The Servlet is only mapped to one path (/api/). Surely you need a pattern (/* would be recommended, if you want to serve the tojen endpoint).

Comment: So your servlet path is what? And what is the patter matching your token endpoint in Spring Security? They have to line up remember?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be so hard. I must be missing something basic. I still get 404

my web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>KMA Web Application</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.kmaApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>kmaApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <!--<param-value>-->
                <!--classpath:/spring/servlet-context.xml-->
                <!--classpath:/spring/kmaAppContext.xml-->
                <!--classpath:/spring/security/kmaSecurityContext.xml-->
            <!--</param-value>-->
            <param-value>
                classpath:/spring/kmaAppContext.xml
                classpath:/spring/servlet-context.xml
                classpath:/spring/security/kmaSecurityContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>kmaApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My kmaSecurityContext

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.kma.kmawebservice.services.security.MAUserDetailsService">
    </bean>

    <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </bean>


    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
            <!--<security:user-service id="userService">-->
                <!--<security:user name="test" password="pass" authorities="customer" />-->
            <!--</security:user-service>-->
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />

    </security:http>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="kma/client"/>
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Authorization Server Configuration of the server is used to provide
    implementations of the client details service and token services and to enable
    or disable certain aspects of the mechanism globally. -->
    <oauth:authorization-server
            client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <!-- Client Definition -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

        <oauth:client client-id="kma-client"
                      authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect"
                      authorities="ROLE_USER"
                      redirect-uri="/web"
                      scope="read,write,trust"
                      access-token-validity="30"
                      refresh-token-validity="600"/>

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <!-- Token Store  -->
    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"/>
    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
        <!-- VIV -->
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <!--<security:http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true">-->

        <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/admin/**"-->
                                <!--access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />-->
        <!--<security:http-basic />-->
        <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**"-->
                                <!--access="isAuthenticated()" />-->
        <!--<security:http-basic />-->
    <!--</security:http>-->

</beans>
```

my servlet-context.xml

```
<beans
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kma.kmawebservice.controllers, com.kma.feedback.controllers, com.kma.kmabackend.controllers"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/WEB-INF/" />

</beans>
```

when accessing

> http://localhost:8080/kma/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123

I get HTTP Status 404 - /kma/oauth/token
My war name is kma.war

The log shows

```
.20:44:42.375 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token' 
.20:44:42.375 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token' 
.20:44:42.376 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 
.20:44:42.376 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 
.20:44:42.377 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 
.20:44:42.377 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 
.20:44:42.378 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter' 
.20:44:42.378 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter' 
.20:44:42.380 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.c.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter - Request is to process authentication 
.20:44:42.380 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.c.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter - Request is to process authentication 
.20:44:42.380 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider 
.20:44:42.380 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider 
.20:44:42.381 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.c.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d7afe829: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@93b2ea19: Username: kma-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER 
.20:44:42.381 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.c.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d7afe829: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@93b2ea19: Username: kma-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER 
.20:44:42.382 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter' 
.20:44:42.382 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter' 
.20:44:42.384 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter' 
.20:44:42.384 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter' 
.20:44:42.385 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter' 
.20:44:42.385 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter' 
.20:44:42.386 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d7afe829: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@93b2ea19: Username: kma-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER' 
.20:44:42.386 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d7afe829: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@93b2ea19: Username: kma-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER' 
.20:44:42.388 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter' 
.20:44:42.388 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter' 
.20:44:42.388 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor' 
.20:44:42.388 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor' 
.20:44:42.389 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token' 
.20:44:42.389 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token' 
.20:44:42.389 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123; Attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] 
.20:44:42.389 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123; Attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] 
.20:44:42.390 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d7afe829: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@93b2ea19: Username: kma-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER 
.20:44:42.390 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d7afe829: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@93b2ea19: Username: kma-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER 
.20:44:42.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@2b65b068, returned: 0 
.20:44:42.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@2b65b068, returned: 0 
.20:44:42.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@2120921a, returned: 1 
.20:44:42.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@2120921a, returned: 1 
.20:44:42.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful 
.20:44:42.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful 
.20:44:42.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object 
.20:44:42.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object 
.20:44:42.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain 
.20:44:42.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=kma-client&username=admin@kma.com&password=123 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain 
.20:44:42.392 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally 
.20:44:42.392 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally 
.20:44:42.392 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed 
.20:44:42.392 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: as a note, i also tried changing the servlet mapping pattern to /*

Comment: The servlet mapping has to match the security config. Is the log different when you map to /*?

Comment: Added log as new answer